# Cocoa:NSTableView repeated loading data the label in cell

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview

As I scroll up and down fast or refresh datas by tableView.reloadData(), the labels and images was bolder and bolder,it was loaded many times.
My code is simple as follows:

```
    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("customCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        let infos:Info = dataSource[row] as Info
        let nameLabel:NSTextField = NSTextField()
        nameLabel.bordered = false
        nameLabel.editable = false
        nameLabel.stringValue = infos.name
        nameLabel.textColor = NSColor.darkGrayColor()
        cell.addSubview(nameLabel)
        let imageView:NSImageView = NSImageView()
        imageView.image = infos.icon
        cell.addSubview(imageView)

        return cell
}
```

The snapshot like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table views make use of a cell [*reuse queue*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableViewOverview/TableViewOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH2-SW10) to make them more performant, particularly when they contain lots of rows. This is similar to how UITableView works on iOS if you're familiar with it.

In brief: when you scroll the table view, the views for the rows which move offscreen are not deallocated but instead put into a 'reuse queue' for later. When you call the `makeViewWithIdentifier(_:owner:)` function, the NSTableView first checks this queue for views that it can reuse: if it contains any, the function will return one of these to you; if not, it will make a new view and return that.

I suspect the problem here is that you're adding subviews to the cell view in `tableView(_:viewForTableColumn:row:)`, which is executed every time a new row is set up. Since the cells you're adding subviews to are reused, every time a new row scrolls into view you add another label and image view to it, which is stacked on top of the previous one and creates the bolding effect you describe.

If you're designing your cells in Interface Builder, you can add a text field and image view to your prototype cell and connect NSTableCellView's `imageView` and `textField` outlets to these views so you can access them in `tableView(_:viewForTableColumn:row:)`